# Why was this question closed? (policy for reference requests)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, questions

As per the text of the re-open thread, it wouldn't fit to add this to that queue. However, I am curious to understand why this question was closed: [Algebra and Geometry book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294617/algebra-and-geometry-book).

I have no vested interest in it, but found what OP asked for of some interest to myself - more so than the often metaphysical/esoteric reference requests I've noticed, which remain open. It is actionable, with a clearly defined possible answer. The "free" is worrisome as it might encourage (or ask for?) illegally free copies; the question seems impatient and mildly pushy; and its formulation could certainly be much better.

But I don't understand why it was closed; and, in the context of other reference requests, don't see why it should be.

Comment: These are actually two questions, not one. I think there is some agreement that we don't want that. The formulation does the rest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tone, presentation, and nuance do matter; it is probably incorrect to cast this as simply a matter of policy on reference requests.

(disclaimer: I did not vote to close, and I have not attempted to make my own judgement on the question)

Comment: I personally dislike muchly the «very urgent» questions... I did not vote to close, though.

Comment: Oh I disliked the style too; but the content was one of the more actually interesting topics i've seen here. So the reason "not constructive"..,just didn't seem to be right.

Comment: It's obvious who voted to close. Why mentioning it? I also didn't...

Comment: @draks...: confused - no one did, or am I missing something? Only name I recognized on the close vote list is a strong mathematician who I've seen only respectful in his answers. From my end, there is certainly nothing personal meant, and I hope that is clear.

Comment: @draks: Mainly, I just wanted to emphasize that I don't hold a belief either way; I've been misunderstood as promoting a point of view when I'm merely trying to describe it far more often than I'd like.

Comment: @gnometorule When you look at the [closed] question, it's obvious who voted to close. No reason to point out, that someone didn't. I just wondered...no reason for a discussion and I agree with you on "Why was this question closed?"

Comment: @gnometorule What do you mean by <<Only name I recognized on the close vote list is a strong mathematician who I've seen only respectful in his answers>> ? Does this mean that other "less advanced" people can't vote to close?

Comment: @BenjaLim: I was confused by what I took to mean that this had been made personal. In addition to not having meant anything personal, I meant to point out that I only recognized one name of a member who is (from his contributions) very good (certainly 'better than me') and respectful; and I wouldn't judge 4 people w/o knowing a little about their behavior on this site. People can vote in accordance with the rules of the site. I could add to this, but frankly don't really see where this would lead.

Answer (score 2):

Being one of the people that voted to close here's my reason.

Firstly the question asks for two books on algebra and geometry that contain problems and theorems. Now how broad is such a question? I ask myself at what level should such a book be? Is it for a course?  There are books ranging from:

1. "Pre-calculus for dummies"
2. Dummit and Foote
3. Atiyah - Macdonald
4. Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory
5. Hilton and Stammbach

and it goes on not just in one direction but in ***many directions***! If you click on the "close" button you will see:

> > **Not a Real question:** It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

The question as it stands fits perfectly the second line in the description above.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. It was later added as a comment "Olympiad", and maybe you voted prior to that update, in which case I understand.